# Unicode errors when printing python beautiful soup object

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stats.swehockey.se/Teams/Info/TeamRoster/10333').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

This code producing the following error

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xbb' in position 1509: ordinal not in range(128)`

I have tried several work arounds but they all have some drawback. After searching on stackoverflow, I found the solution of changing .stdout, like this:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stderr)

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stats.swehockey.se/Teams/Info/TeamRoster/10333').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

I no longer get the error, however, the output is no longer directed towards the terminal. I'm not sure why this is happening. Using the `.prettify('utf-8')` method also gets rid of the error and produces output, however, the resulting object is a string, and not a beautiful soup object, and thus has none of the associated bs methods (e.g. .find_all()). A similar problem arises with the `.encode('utf-8')` approach.

Also, I've noticed that in the output, there are many \r and \n characters still in the beautiful soup object instead of the pure html content.

I want a beautiful soup object without any of the \r or \n characters that I can print to the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```py
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stats.swehockey.se/Teams/Info/TeamRoster/10333').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
```

`sauce` is of type `bytes`. When you pass that into `bs.BeautifulSoup()`, BeautifulSoup attempts to decode those bytes as an `ascii` string, and fails, because it is actually a `utf-8` string -- according to both the `Content-Type` response header (`text/html; charset=utf-8`) and also the `meta` tag at the start of the html document (`<meta charset="utf-8" />`).

The first argument for `bs.BeautifulSoup()`, `markup`, takes *a string or a file-like object representing markup to be parsed*. You should explicitly decode those bytes as a `utf-8` encoded string, and use that instead of the raw bytes, like so:

```py
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://stats.swehockey.se/Teams/Info/TeamRoster/10333').read().decode('utf-8')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
```

> Also, I've noticed that in the output, there are many \r and \n characters still in the beautiful soup object instead of the pure html content.
>
> I want a beautiful soup object without any of the \r or \n characters that I can print to the terminal.

The `\r` and `\n` characters are just *representations* of the newline character. If you were to print these, or view them in a text editor, they would show up as actual newlines.